# How do I put an 'if clause' in an SQL string?

Tags: mysql, sql

So here's what I want to do on my *MySQL* database.

I would like to do:

```
SELECT *
    FROM itemsOrdered
    WHERE purchaseOrder_ID = '@purchaseOrdered_ID'
        AND status = 'PENDING'
```

If that would not return any rows, which is possible through `if(dr.HasRows == false)`, I would now create an `UPDATE` in the `purchaseOrder` database:

```
UPDATE purchaseOrder
    SET purchaseOrder_status = 'COMPLETED'
    WHERE purchaseOrder_ID = '@purchaseOrder_ID'
```

How would I be able to make this process a little shorter?

Comment: the itemsOrdered database has a unique ID called `itemsOrdered_ID` and has recurring `purchaseOrder_ID` values

Comment: the `purchaseorder` database on the other hand has the unique ID `purchaseOrder_ID`

Answer (score 495, accepted):

For your specific query, you can do:

```
UPDATE purchaseOrder
    SET purchaseOrder_status = 'COMPLETED'
    WHERE purchaseOrder_ID = '@purchaseOrder_ID' and
          not exists (SELECT *
                      FROM itemsOrdered WHERE purchaseOrder_ID = '@purchaseOrdered_ID' AND status = 'PENDING'
                     )
```

However, I might guess that you are looping at a higher level.  To set all such values, try this:

```
UPDATE purchaseOrder
    SET purchaseOrder_status = 'COMPLETED'
    WHERE not exists (SELECT 1
                      FROM itemsOrdered
                      WHERE itemsOrdered.purchaseOrder_ID = purchaseOrder.purchaseOrdered_ID AND
                            status = 'PENDING'
                      limit 1
                     )
```

Comment: Actually in MySQL, the correlated subquery should be among the most efficient approaches, assuming there is an index on itemsOrdered.purchaseOrder_ID.

Comment: @eggyal . . . I agree that without an index the correlated version is perhaps less performant than the join (depends on various factors, such as multiplication of rows).  With an index, though, it should be better than a join because it should stop the index scan at the first match.  Check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subquery-optimization-with-exists.html.

Answer (score 65):

You can use the multiple-table `UPDATE` syntax to effect an `ANTI-JOIN` between `purchaseOrder` and `itemsOrdered`:

```sql
UPDATE purchaseOrder p LEFT JOIN itemsOrdered i
    ON p.purchaseOrder_ID = i.purchaseOrder_ID
   AND i.status = 'PENDING'
SET    p.purchaseOrder_status = 'COMPLETED'
WHERE  p.purchaseOrder_ID = '@purchaseOrder_ID'
   AND i.purchaseOrder_ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 57):

Since MySQL doesn't support `if exists(*Your condition*) (*Write your query*)`, you can achieve an 'if clause' by writing like this:

```
(*Write your insert or update query*) where not exists (*Your condition*)
```

Answer (score 32):

You can also use the following query to check if the record exists and then update it:

```
if not exists(select top 1 fromFROM itemsOrdered
    WHERE purchaseOrder_ID = '@purchaseOrdered_ID'
        AND status = 'PENDING' )
Begin

UPDATE purchaseOrder 
    SET purchaseOrder_status = 'COMPLETED'
    WHERE purchaseOrder_ID = '@purchaseOrder_ID

End
```

Answer (score 28):

```
Select FROM t1
    WHERE s11 > ANY
        (SELECT col1,col2 FROM t2
            WHERE NOT EXISTS
                (SELECT * FROM t3
                    WHERE ROW(5*t2.s1,77)=
                        (SELECT 50,11*s1 FROM t4 UNION SELECT 50,77 FROM
                            (SELECT * FROM t5) AS t5)));
```

Comment: I'm struggling to see how this answers the question at all?

Comment: @theMayer Me too but it's a pretty nice answer

Comment: Congratulations, Your code has been selected as an obfuscated code.

Comment: I guess this is an example of what else we can do using `SQL`

Answer (score 18):

```
if not exists(select top 1 fromFROM itemsOrdered
    WHERE purchaseOrder_ID = '@purchaseOrdered_ID'
        AND status = 'PENDING' )
Begin

UPDATE purchaseOrder 
    SET purchaseOrder_status = 'COMPLETED'
    WHERE purchaseOrder_ID = '@purchaseOrder_ID

End
```

Comment: it will be great if u explain the answer also, code only answers are not helpful for future users

Answer (score 12):

after sql server 2008 provide `Merge` to insert,update and delete operation based on single match statement, also that allows you to join. below sample example might be helps you.

```
MERGE Target AS T
USING Source AS S
ON (T.EmployeeID = S.EmployeeID) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND S.EmployeeName LIKE 'S%' 
    THEN INSERT(EmployeeID, EmployeeName) VALUES(S.EmployeeID, S.EmployeeName)
WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE SET T.EmployeeName = S.EmployeeName
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND T.EmployeeName LIKE 'S%'
    THEN DELETE 
OUTPUT $action, inserted.*, deleted.*;
```

like this you can insert, update and delete in one statements.

and for more information you can refer official documents on 
 https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 11):

If the table contains millions of records then the following query will work fast.

```
UPDATE PO
SET PO.purchaseOrder_status = 'COMPLETED'
FROM purchaseOrder PO
LEFT OUTER JOIN itemsOrdered IOD ON IOD.purchaseOrder_ID = PO.purchaseOrdered_ID and IOD.status = 'PENDING'
WHERE IOD.purchaseOrder_ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 4):

You can declare a variable holding the number of returned results on select query.
You can then run the update statement if this variable is more than 0

```
    Declare @ResultCount int
    SELECT @ResultCount = count(*) FROM itemsOrdered WHERE purchaseOrder_ID = '@purchaseOrdered_ID' AND status = 'PENDING'        
    If @ResultCount > 0
UPDATE purchaseOrder SET purchaseOrder_status = 'COMPLETED' WHERE purchaseOrder_ID = '@purchaseOrder_ID'
```