# HTML link that redirect to div which have no id

Tags: html, hyperlink, tags

I want to make a link that redirects to `"Try it yourself"` in https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

But when I inspect the section that says `Try it yourself` in above link, it says that it has no `id`.

To understand more about my question, I want to make a link similar to this. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13991817/how-do-i-put-an-if-clause-in-an-sql-string/13991857#13991857`

So my question is how can I get a link of specific div of web page?

UPDATE: is there any default ID (like 45253435) for each div? Then how can I get that?

Comment: You can get that div by using var divs = getElementsByTagName("div");

Comment: My question is not javascript, can you give me the link that redirect to "Try it yourself" in https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp?

Comment: I think you're out of luck. In order to use the HTML Bookmark feature, the element you're linking to needs to have an `id`. Look at [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp) about half-way down. (I can't link to the specific spot on the page, either :/ )